# get user's location info using facebook ios sdk in swift

Tags: xcode, facebook-graph-api, swift

I couldn't find any info about getting user's location info in swift and xcode 6

I tried

```
var fbcity = user.objectForKey("location")
        var fbcountry = user.objectForKey("country")
```

But didn't work.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could supply us with a little more information, e.g. which Facebook SDK you are using and what parameters `FBSDKGraphRequest` has to return `user`. Note that there is no specific information about country, the `location` field in the user node when your send a graph request for the user profile. It will return the subfields: `id` and `name`, where name is

With the latest Facebook iOS SDK 4.0 you can do something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loginView.delegate = self

    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        fetchUserData()
    } else {
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    }       
}

func fetchUserData() {
    let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in                
        if error != nil {
             // Process error
             println("Error: \(error)")
        } else {              
             let location: NSDictionary! = result.valueForKey("location") as NSDictionary
             let city: NSString = location.valueForKey("name") as NSString                   
        }
    })
}
```

More detailed info can be found on [Facebook Graph API User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) page.