# Facebook Graph API does not return location, why?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

Retrieving location amoung `firstname`, `gender`, `photo url`, `id`, but location (i.e. country, city) is not returned. Any idea why?

```
FBLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile"]
let gr2 : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,gender,first_name,location,picture.type(large)"])
let _location = data["location"] as? String // this is nil
```

Comment: Because you did not ask the user for permission to access their location.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211962/get-users-location-info-using-facebook-ios-sdk-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

While requesting for the permissions from your app, add `user_location` in the scope.